# The use of "prevent" with another verb

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Which is more idiomatic/correct or formal/technical:

- X prevents Y from moving further into Z
- X prevents Y to move further into Z
- X prevents the diffusion of Y further into the Z

The first sentence seems like a template for the usage of "prevent". It is usually "prevent from". How about the second and third ones? I'm also not sure about the gap between "diffusion" and "further"

Answer (score 1):

Example 1 is correct and idiomatic.

Example 2 is wrong. It would have to be rewritten as:

> X does not allow/permit Y to move further into Z

I am not a chemist or a physicist but Example 3 appears to be grammatically correct if strange to my uneducated ear.

Comment: I would consider **further** in *diffusion further into* to be misplaced.  I'd say rather **it prevents further diffusion of Y into the Z**.